# Index action redirecting to show action without post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple app. Part of the app is a simple search function that searches the database and sends the parameters to the "show" action.

Right now that search field is in the "index" view.

But, instead of the index view showing...it automatically tries to send me to

localhost:3000/zips/1/3/13 # <~ I assume it's selecting all and trying to redirect it to the show action?

Here is my action from the controller

```
  def index
    @zips = Zip.search(params[:search])
    if @zips.blank?
      redirect_to zips_path, :notice => "Zipcode #{params[:search]} is not eligible for Local Delivery"
    else
      redirect_to zip_path @zips
    end
  end
```

Here is my index view

```
<h1>
  Pick-up/Delivery Eligibility
</h1>
<h3>
Based on U.S. Zipcode, Canadian Postal Code
</h3>
<p class="el">
  To find out if you qualify for 4over&#146;s local delivery service,
  please enter your <nobr>U.S. 5 digit zip code, or</nobr> your 
  <nobr>Canadian 6 character Postal Code,</nobr> then click submit.

<%= form_tag zips_path, :method => "get" do %>
  <p><%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %> | <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %></p>
<% end %>
```

How can I tell the index action to "wait" until I submit the form and now do a "select *" and pass that?

The behavior I want is I want the index page to show and only pass the parameters to the "show" action when the form is submitted

Also, this is my model file

```
 def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ['zip LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else    
      find(:all)
    end
  end
```

I'm running ruby 1.9 on rails 4

I'm new to rails (and OOP in general) so any help would be great!

Comment: Nothing personal but I think you don't understand what you are doing and you should start with Rails Guides.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel Nothing personal taken! I admit that I am ignorant in what I'm doing. I'm going through these little exercises at work so I can learn through trail and error. I'll practice also with the guides as well! Vielen dank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `redirect_to zip_path @zips` which uses `show` action when `@zips.blank?` is false. I would look at case where `@zips.blank?` is false

Comment: Thanks for that tip! I actually got it to work with this:

`elsif @zips.count > 1
      true`

I'm pretty sure that's not best practice...but at least it got me the behavior that I want